# Angular $http, wait until get answer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service which exposes some utilities methods that are executed using $http

```
// my service declaration
// $http gets injected

this.getName = function(){
   $http(options)
   .then(
      function(data){
         return data;
      }, 
      function(error){
         return 'some error';
      }
   );
};

this.getAge = function(){
   $http(options)
   .then(
      function(data){
         return data;
      }, 
      function(error){
         return 'some error';
      }
   );
};
```

In my controllers, I get this service injected in order to expose those utilities methods such as:

```
// my controller declaration
var service = $injector.resolve('$myService');
```

Then, from here I want to call the utilities methods such as:

```
console.log(service.getName());
```

or do something like

```
if(service.getName() == ''){

}
```

The problem is that when I try to do that, the method start the async HTTP call and returns empty, while only later the answer is returned. How can I address this issue?

Comment: You can return from an AJAX call - you either use promises or callbacks.

Comment: http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Comment: I don't get the down-voting but thanks for the answer